# Add to cart button function

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a problem where I want to add a product from the catalogue to cart. I manage to do it for a single product but when I refresh back and add another product, the previous product disappear and only show the latest product that I choose. I'm stuck here and don't know how to do it. I hope someone could help me

Below is the code that I have tried

Product.java

```
package Model;

public class Product {

    private int id;

    private String prodName;

    private String desc;

    private double pricePerUnit;

    private int qtyInStock;

    public Product(int id, String prodName, String desc, double pricePerUnit, int qtyInStock) {

        this.id = id;

        this.prodName = prodName;

        this.desc = desc;

        this.pricePerUnit = pricePerUnit;

        this.qtyInStock = qtyInStock;

    }

    public String getProdName() {

        return prodName;

    }

    public double getPricePerUnit() {

        return pricePerUnit;

    }

    public int getQtyInStock() {

        return qtyInStock;

    }

    @Override

    public String toString() {

        return "ProductModel{" + "id=" + id + ", prodName=" + prodName + ", desc=" + desc + ", pricePerUnit=" + pricePerUnit + ", qtyInStock=" + qtyInStock + '}';

    }    

}
```

ListOf.java

```
package Model;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;

public final class ListOf {

    public static List<Product> products = new ArrayList();

    static{

        products.add(new Product(1,"Academic Book","Learn to program",50.00,100));

        products.add(new Product(2,"Notebook","Latest notebook in the market",5500.00,10));

        products.add(new Product(3,"Travel Charger","Travel Adapter",15.00,10));

        products.add(new Product(4,"Lipstick","Red Matter Color",25.00,100));

    }

    public static List<Product> cartItems = new ArrayList();

}
```

ShoppingController.java

```
package Controller;

import Model.ListOf;
import Model.Product;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet(name = "ShoppingController", urlPatterns = {"/shopping"})
public class ShoppingController extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        //step 1: fetch data
        List<Product> result = ListOf.products
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        request.setAttribute("productList", result);
        //step 2: do business logic

        //step 3: generate output
        RequestDispatcher dis=request.getRequestDispatcher("shopping.jsp");          
        dis.forward(request, response);         
    }
}
```

CartController.java

```
package Controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet(name = "CartController", urlPatterns = {"/cart"})
public class CartController extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        RequestDispatcher dis=request.getRequestDispatcher("cart.jsp");          
        dis.forward(request, response);         
    }

}
```

The output should be the list of product that the user has clicked "Add to cart". It should be more than 1 product if the user clicked more than 1 product but I only manage to get only 1 product in the cart and the previous product will disappear. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you think you need to maintain cart at session level rather than at request level?

Comment: Yes, i think it should be maintained in session-level for each user, but I still new to jsp and I don't know how to do it yet.

Comment: `request.getSession().setAttribute("productList", result);`

Comment: this error appears org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException